# Error when trying to add new line in the end of command

Tags: linux, bash

I have this code `#!/bin/bash
ls \n`

When i try to run it it keeps saying

```
ls: cannot access n: No such file or directory
```

I have many scripts that i want to add new line in the end of them but all of them have the same error.

Comment: Do you want a newline printed after the output of `ls` when the script runs? or a newline in the script itself? So far the two answers seem to disagree on this. And please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add newline but literal string `\n` into the files. To append newline in the end of the file, just `echo` an empty string. E.g.

```
# use >> to append an empty line to the end

echo "" >> target.txt
```

Comment: i must do it only in two lines else it won't work

Comment: @YassinBahri AFIAK, impossible. Though represented by `\n`, newline is actually a **non-printable** character marking the start of another line. So the total line number increases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a newline after a command called in a script succeeds you can use:

```
ls && printf "\n"
```

or if you always want to print the newline:

```
ls ; printf "\n"
```